# Laravel $touch for updating updated_at

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a doubt regarding `$touch` in Laravel. What I understood is, `$touch` can be used to update model or relationship without updating any other column. But what I am trying is, I need to update user table, whatever changes occurred in other users related table. 
It can be create, update or delete. In my case, `$touch` not working with the relationship for delete.

```
//touch
protected $touches = ['somerelation'];

//relationship
public function somerelation(){
    return $this->belongsTo('someModel', 'key_id');
}

public setSomeRelationAttribute(){
  $this->someRelation()->delete();
}
```

This is what i tried. updated_at in users working fine with create and update. But not for delete.

Is it because touch is only applicable for add and update?

I make sure, touch not working for delete in all relations, by checking DB values.

I need to ensure that my findings are true, that touch not works for delete

Comment: Ca you write delete code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are calling `touch()` on the existing model for example:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$post->touch(); // this updates just this model
```

So there is no way a delete can work on a row that you are deleting.

But on a parent model it does work, so for example you have post with comments, in the Comment model you add:

```
protected $touches = [ 'post' ];

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

Even if you delete a comment this will update the Post. [Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/05deb0dac149705dd860d9757a38a80c5b5f6247/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1122) is the implementation of the delete method and specifically the line which will touch the parent models.

-- EDIT

Improve your relationship to one of this:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

// or

return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
```

Comment: But its now working in my case. Let me check once again. Is there any possibilities for its not to update?

Comment: @reshma you should edit your question and show some code, there is no way I can answer it without looking at your code. Because your findings are not true that it does not work for delete, I showed you the implementation of the framework.

Comment: @reshma take a look at my edit. Your belongs to does not seem correct. You can avoid the second parameter as it is the same as the function so Laravel will use `user_id` anyway.

Comment: I am not using the exact format. Thats why i specify the second parameter. And i dont think that there is an issue with relation. Because its work fine with create and update.

Comment: Yes I did, and it works fine. You should show the exact code, and the way you use the `delete` because I showed you the source code which does call the touch on the owners.. so there is no way it does not work for delete.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/05deb0dac149705dd860d9757a38a80c5b5f6247/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2044 This was the method am redirecting.  I do have a Mutator and its calling my delete function

Comment: Then you should call the `delete` method on the model, not on the query builder as the model calls `performDeleteOnModel` which does in turn calls the delete on the query builder. So you should not skip steps in order for the relationships to get updated, otherwise you will need to manually touch the relationship. Just don't claim that something does not work when you are skipping steps.

Comment: And to keep sharing neither do `insert` nor `update` call touch on the relationship in the `Builder` class. So those do not work too if you directly call them. Which makes create and update not to work. [Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/05deb0dac149705dd860d9757a38a80c5b5f6247/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1979) is a proof

Answer (score 1):

For [delete() method in Eloquent Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/05deb0dac149705dd860d9757a38a80c5b5f6247/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1108) relations in $touch will be updated.

If it calls, [delete() in query-builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/05deb0dac149705dd860d9757a38a80c5b5f6247/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2044) , it will not touch relations in $touch.

Comment: You are welcomed that I helped :) you can accept my answer then, and not provide your own, as it is already answered above.

Comment: I just provided both mehods, as mine is in comment section. Thanks lot for your time